# How to get all users with a specific permission

Tags: 8, users

Is there a way to retrieve all users with a specific permission (eg "Post comments").
I only found the possibility to get them by their role:

```
Drupal::entityQuery('user')
->condition('status', 1)
->condition('roles', 'administrator')
->execute();
```

or

```
Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')
->getStorage('user')
->loadByProperties(['roles' => 'administrator']);
```

Answer (score 5):

I had to get the roles that had a given permission to get users with a permission, example:

```
$roles = user_role_names(FALSE, 'example_permission');
$rids = array_keys($roles);

$uids = Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('user')->getQuery()
  ->condition('roles', $rids, 'IN')
  ->execute();
```

Apparently thats what Drupal core does in the permission filter for views, see:
\Drupal\user\Plugin\views\filter\Permissions

Hope that helps some!